# Something about the idea of Molarity is confusing me

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, concentration

Okay, so molarity is defined as **moles of solute per liter of solution**. It is used to describe the concentration. So in the lab, when I see a bottle labeled something like $\mathrm{3.5~M}~\ce{H2SO4}$, is it saying that the **only** chemical in the bottle is this $\ce{H2SO4}$?

Because the way I think of it is "there are 3.5 moles of $\ce{H2SO4}$ per liter of solution". The word "solution" is kind of throwing me off because it makes me feel like they are saying that there is more than just $\ce{H2SO4}$ in the bottle. Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you need at least 2 solutes to make a solution?

I don't know why I'm having such a hard time grasping this. But any help would be awesome!

Comment: @michael I dont know whether this will answer your query but I had a similar doubt long time back. You should look into it http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/671/the-mole-is-used-extensively-in-chemistry-why-not-elsewhere . This is how i remembers a mole **1 mole=6.2*10^23 of something**. something includes atom,molecules, cow, aliens, stars etc :)

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between molarity and concentration?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/19702/7951)

Answer (score 7):

> Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you need at least 2 solutes to make a solution?

You are, unfortunately, incorrect. In wet chemistry, you need just a *solvent*$^\dagger$ and at least one *solute* to make a solution.  While this does mean that you need at least two *constituents* to make up a solution, you do not need at least two *solutes*.

> ... is it saying that the ONLY chemical in the bottle is this $\ce{H2SO4}$?

It depends on your definition of a *chemical*:

- If you consider water to be a chemical, then ***no***: there are two chemicals in the bottle$^\ddagger$, $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{H2SO4}$.
- If you are not considering water to be a chemical, then ***yes***: the only chemical in the bottle$^\ddagger$ is $\ce{H2SO4}$.

<sub>$^\dagger$ If not specified, the solvent is almost always water.</sub>

<sub>$^\ddagger$ Except for small amounts of inevitable impurities.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Brian has the correct answer.

I'd like to add, however, that in the most general sense, we don't have to take a molar to mean a mole of **solute** per liter of **solution**. I've actually seen it used to mean "a mole of **stuff** per liter of **space**" for particular values of stuff.

Since the above sentence isn't exactly self-explanatory, let's take a look at a few examples.

#### Example 1: Water

At 4 °C, water has a density of 1000 g/L. Water has a molar mass of 18.02 g/mol. This means that in a liter of water at 4 °C, there are:

$$
1~\mathrm{L} \cdot 1000 ~\frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{L}} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{mol}}{18.02 \mathrm{g}} = 55.5 ~\mathrm{mol}
$$

Since there are 55.5 moles of water per liter of water, we can actually say that, at 4 °C, water is 55.5 molar. (See [Example 3 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_concentration#Examples)).

Note how this works: there is a certain amount of **stuff** (in this case, water) per amount of **space** (one liter, or one cubic decimeter). It doesn't matter that we don't have a solution--since there's stuff, and it takes up space, we can calculate a molarity for it.

#### Example 2: Ideal gas

An ideal gas takes up 22.4 L per mole, at STP. Taking the inverse of this, we find that it is 0.0446 moles/L. Therefore, the concentration of an idea gas at STP is 0.0446 molar.

Again, there's a certain amount of stuff (one mole of ideal gas) and a certain amount of space (22.4 liters), which allows us to calculate a molarity. The fact that the substance is pure doesn't stop us from writing a concentration for it.

#### A note of caution

This will **NOT** work for a measure of concentration like molality, because molality is defined by the amount of **solvent** used. It also won't usually work for things like normality, since you (usually) need to be in solution to generate ions.

Comment: Excellent points. I hate normality -- it doesn't even have to be ionic. For example, for EDTA, typically its normality is equal to its molarity, since it binds metals $1:1$. If you don't the 'customary' conversion from molarity to normality, its *impossible* to identify logically. Small wonder the term is obsolete!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the best way to clear your doubt. Have you ever prepared tea? What are the main ingredients of tea?

$$\ce{water~(or~milk) + tea~leaves -> tea}$$

It's the addition of tea leaves which changes water to tea. Depending on how strong you want a tea you can add one teaspoon, two teaspoons or n number of teaspoons of tea leaves.

Similarly, in $\mathrm{3.5~M}~\ce{H2SO4}$ solution it contains:

$$\ce{H2SO4~(solute) + H2O~(solvent) -> H2SO4~solution}$$

To my knowledge there is no 100 percent pure $\ce{H2SO4}$ available commercially. The commercially available $\ce{H2SO4}$ is 96 percent $\ce{H2SO4}$ with a concentration approximately of 18 molar. See [this link](http://crescentok.com/staff/jaskew/isr/safety/cabconc.htm).